# Stable homotopy groups of $QX$

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, loop-spaces, classifying-spaces

If $X$ is a space, we can form $QX=\varinjlim \Omega^n\Sigma^nX$ which is an infinite loop space with homotopy groups $\pi_i(QX)=\pi^{s}_i(X)$ the stable homotopy groups of $X.$ But these are the *unstable* homotopy groups of $QX.$

**Q:** Is there any similar expression for the *stable* homotopy groups of $QX$?

Just to get some feeling, **I would already be very happy to know just what $\pi_0^s(QS^0)$ is**. If I understand things correctly, it should be the same as $\pi_0^s(B\Sigma_\infty^+),$ but I still don't know how to compute it.

I guess $\pi_i^s(QX)$ seems like some sort of "secondary stable homotopy group" of $X$. But there is no reason to stop there. How about groups $\pi_i(Q^nX)$ which should be "$n$-ary stable homotopy groups" of $X$ - what sort of information do they carry?

Of course then we could start forming other very silly objects such as about some sort of stabilizations $\pi_{i+n}(Q^nX)$ as $n\to\infty$ (does that make sense and/or produce anything sensible?) and so on, but at that point I am burried so deep in things that I don't understand that it's a bit pointless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Snaith splitting" gives the following spectrum level statement: for a pointed connected space $X$, there is a weak equivalence:
$$
\Sigma^\infty_+ (\Omega^\infty \Sigma^\infty X) \simeq \bigvee_{n \geq 0} \Sigma^\infty (X^{\wedge n})_{h\Sigma_n}
$$
There is also an unbased version:
$$
\Sigma^\infty (\Omega^\infty \Sigma^\infty X) \simeq \bigvee_{n \geq 1} \Sigma^\infty (X^{\wedge n})_{h\Sigma_n}
$$
This gives an isomorphism on the level of stable homotopy groups:
$$
\pi_*^{s}((QX)_+) = \pi_*(\Sigma^\infty_+ \Omega^\infty \Sigma^\infty X) \cong \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} \pi_*^s((X^{\wedge n})_{h\Sigma_n})
$$

When the space $X$ is not connected, one needs to add a group-completion to get the correct statement. The net effect is that on $\pi_0$ we get an isomorphism between $\pi_0^s((QX)_+)$ and the group algebra on the free abelian group on $\pi_0(X)$: it is freely generated as a commutative ring by generators coming from $\pi_0(X)$ and their inverses. In the case of $QS^0$ this becomes the Laurent polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[t^{\pm 1}]$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Tyler, this is pretty much pretty much precisely what I wanted.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind an after-question - what are $\pi_i^s((QS^0)_+)$ for $i\ge 1$? I imagine those nasty group actions should start being relevant, but then you mention group-completion is needed and I don't know how that mingles with the actions of symmetric groups.

Comment: @user82454 Well, it's hard to give exact statements. The whole thing splits off a big component which is essentially a bunch of copies of the stable homotopy groups of spheres; $\pi_1$ is $\Bbb Z[t^{\pm 1}] \otimes (\Bbb Z/2^2)$; and you're getting a colimit of the stable homotopy groups of $B\Sigma_n$.

Comment: Particular questions might be answerable but the whole answer is probably not.

Comment: It's lucky than that I wasn't really looking for the whole answer, but just a bunch of particulars to try to get some feeling for it. :) Maybe it would be helpful if you could explain a bit more explicitly _where_ to apply group-completion? But in either case thank you immensely for all your time and effort in explaining these probably very simple things to me. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it helps, the group completion comes from the fact that $\pi_0$ of a loop space is always a group but if you look at the other side of the equivalence there is no reason for this to be the case. If you try to do the computation "by hand" you will see that you only really need to fix $\pi_0$.

Comment: @user82454 Sure. So if you take the space $\bigvee (X^{\wedge n})_{h\Sigma_n}$ and take its stable homotopy groups, you're going to get a commutative ring where $\pi_0$ is the free algebra on $\pi_0(X)$, and there's going to be a natural map from this ring to $\pi_*^s(QX_+)$ that sends all the elements of $\pi_0(X)$ to units. The "group completion theorem", in this instance, says that this map between rings becomes an isomorphism after you invert the elements of $\pi_0(X)$ in the source.