# Iterated free infinite loop spaces

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

Let $Q$ denote $\Omega^\infty\circ \Sigma^\infty$ the free infinite loop space functor. Given some space $X$, we see that $QX$ carries all the stable homotopy information about $X$. Naturally I wanted to do this again $QQX$, but examples such as spheres and eilenberg-maclane spaces get too complicated.

There is a natural maps $\iota :X \to QX$ which means we can have a tower:

$$X \to QX \to Q^2X \to \cdots$$

Taking the colimit I can imagine there being an object $Q^\infty X$. So my questions are:

> What is known about repeated applications of the free infinite loop space functor?
>
> Can it be iterated as I have described? What does this describe?

Comment: The Snaith splitting makes it easy t study $Q^rX$ for $r\geq 1$, if this helps you.

Comment: Besides the answer below I wonder what is the difference between $Q^\infty X$ and $Q^\infty(Q^rX)$ when $r\leqslant +\infty$? Aren’t they the same? If so $Q^\infty$ should be a specific kind of functor, different from $Q^r$ for any $r<+\infty$ ?!?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252848/stable-homotopy-groups-of-qx

Comment: There is a result of Freyd that Q-algebras are infinite loop spaces.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you look at Finkelsteins’s PhD thesis!

**L. D. Finkelstein, On the stable Homotopy of infinite loop spaces. PhD thesis. Northwestern University. 1977**

The objective of this thesis is to study $QA$ when $A$ is an infinite loop space which in particular you may take $A=QX$. Also, some papers of Kuhn consider iterated application of $Q$, in particular his papers on/related to Whitehead conjecture. Moreover, the Snaith splitting as mentioned in comments arises from a splitting of the space $QQX$. An application of Snaith splitting shows that understanding $QQQX$ would require one to describe the $r$-adic construction on $QX$ and I am not sure if this is studied in detail. I then conclude that $Q^\infty X$ would be too difficult to describe in terms which allows to do meaningful computations in terms of $X$.

**Added** One of the mail results of Finkelstein, also see section 2 of Kuhn’s paper on homology of James-Hopf maps, is that if $A$ is a suitable infinite loop space then there is a composition
$$QA\to A\times QD_2A\to QA$$
which is a mod 2 equivalence. Note that the thesis is written using Barratt-Eccles $\Gamma^+$ functor. The more general case of this sequence, at an arbitrary prime, appears in Kuhn’s papers related to the Whitehead conjecture.

Comment: What's the title of Finkelstein's thesis?

Comment: Please see the edited question for the citation

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume $X$ is connected with friendly basepoint.  The quick answer goes as follows.  Imagine all subgroups $\Sigma_I < \Sigma_n$ of symmetric groups formed from smaller symmetric groups by iterating products and wreath products.  For such an $I$, let $$D_I(X) = E\Sigma_{n+} \wedge_{\Sigma_I} X^{\wedge n}.$$
Then $Q^{\infty}(X)$ will be the product over all $I$ of the spaces $QD_I(X)$.  As other folks have already hinted at, this follows from the stable splitting of $QX$.

By the way, the cosimplicial resolution $X \rightarrow Q(X) \cdots$ was used by Gunnar Carlsson to deduce the Sullivan conjecture from the Segal Conjecture, and by Greg Arone and Marja Kankaanrinta to give a second construction of the Goodwillie tower of the identity.

Dually, if $X$ is an infinite loopspace, one gets a simplicial infinite loopspace $X \leftarrow QX \cdots$.  Back in the day, I thought about this quite a bit.  When $X=S^1$, the Whitehead conjecture sequence formally splits off this.  For general $X$,  I proved a splitting result about the beginning of this in [Topology 23 (1985), 473-480]. This has a fun conceptual proof (no homology calculations!), works for all primes $p$, and includes Finkelstein's $p=2$ theorem and the Kahn-Priddy theorem at all primes.  I would love to see someone generalize this in some interesting way.

Comment: Can I ask about references for Milner type decomposition of $Q^\infty X$ mentioned above?

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ is connected then $QX$ is stably equivalent to the total extended power $DX$ (by the Snaith splitting, as others have mentioned), so $QQX=QDX$.  If $X$ is not connected then $QX$ is still stably equivalent to a group completion of $DX$.  So it is useful to think about iterating $D$, and then you can go back to thinking about $Q$ if you want.

A key example to consider is as follows: if $G$ is a groupoid, and $SG$ is the free symmetric monoidal category on $G$, then $\Sigma^\infty BG_+=K(SG)$, and $DBG=BSG$.  If $G$ is just a group (considered as a one-object groupoid) then $SG$ is the groupoid of pairs $(P\xrightarrow{p}X)$, where $P$ and $X$ are finite sets, $G$ acts freely on $P$, and $p$ induces a bijection $P/G\to X$.  In other words, $P$ is a $G$-torsor over $X$. 
 More generally, we have $D^nBG=BS^nG$, where $S^nG$ is the groupoid of diagrams 
$$ (P\xrightarrow{p}X_{1}\xrightarrow{f_1}\dotsb\xrightarrow{}X_n), $$
where all the $X_i$ are finite sets, the maps $f_i$ are arbitrary, and $P$ is a $G$-torsor over $X_1$.  The natural map $D^nBG\to D^{n+1}BG$ corresponds to the functor that just adds $X_{n+1}=\{0\}$ at the end.  So $D^\infty BG=BS^\infty G$, where $S^\infty G$ is the analogous groupoid of diagrams 
$$ (P\xrightarrow{p}X_{1}\xrightarrow{f_1}X_2 \to X_3 \to \dotsb ) $$
where $|X_n|=1$ for $n\gg 0$.